# How to solve Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat;'?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing app using Xamarin.Android in VS2019 and using AndroidX. The app was working fine, but now when the app is running I am getting an exception

***'Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat;'.***

I tried by cleaning bin and obj folder, but didn't able to solve the issue. I searched the internet and tried different ways but the issue is still there. Please help me to solve the same.

Thanks and Regards
Gireesh M

Comment: Android.Support.V4.View.ViewCompat comes from the Android Support packages, not from AndroidX. Are you mixing packages? Do you have the AndroidX migration package installed? Are you using some dependencies that haven't been upgraded to AndroidX?

Comment: I have only AndroidX packages Installed via nuget.
I have AndroidX migration packeage 1.0.6.1 installed.

Comment: When migrating to AndroidX, you will need to make some manual namespace changes for scenarios the tool doesn't cover. While the tool will map the correct package, it is encouraged to take a look at the official artifact mappings and class mappings to help your project migration. Please mark the controls reference the correct namespace. Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx#migration-tooling

Comment: I am using 'FlexboxLayoutXamarinBindingAndroid' nuget package for creating flexbox layouts. I think this is causing the problem. Is there any AndroidX alternative for this package?

Comment: When I Changed the 'FlexboxLayoutXamarinBindingAndroid', the error got solved. Thanks for all who helped me.

Comment: @Gireesh If you've solved the issue, please accept your solution as the answer. It will be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 'FlexboxLayoutXamarinBindingAndroid' nuget package for creating flexbox layouts. This is causing the problem.

When I Changed the 'FlexboxLayoutXamarinBindingAndroid', the error got solved. Thanks for all who helped me.

Comment: Congrats! Please mark the solution as the answer, it'll help others who face the similar problem.